# Bitnami Jenkins cannot execute CLI

Tags: ruby, jenkins, bitnami

I just installed BitNami Stack for Jenkins from [App store](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/bitnami-stack-for-jenkins/id598883005?mt=12). In my jobs I want to execute one of my CLI (stored in Library/Ruby/Gems...). However, the console output fails with the following:

```
`getwd': Operation not permitted - getcwd (Errno::EPERM)
```

I suspect that the BitNami Stack for Jenkins (Library/Constainers/com.bitnami.jenkins) does not have the right permissions to execute that CLI?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bitnami developer here. This operation is not permitted by the OS X sandbox system for App Store apps. You can download Jenkins for OS X at https://bitnami.com/stack/jenkins/installer that installs Jenkins in a folder but it is not sandboxed. I hope it helps.